# Enumerate in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is there any way to enumerate rows of query in postgresql?

I have table like this:

```
Table players
id player_id game_id points
```

And I want query like this:

```
SELECT  game_id, <row_number in points group>, <array of ids> 
    FROM players WHERE game_id = %s 
    GROUP BY game_id, points;
```

Comment: Add some sample data (input and output) if you want an answer. It isn't clear what you want

Comment: Desired result set is not clear. Please, specify <row_number in points group>, <array of ids> or provide example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're asking for. The "row number in points group" is a straight forward [window function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html) application but I don't know what "array of ids" means.

Given date like this:

```
 id | player_id | game_id | points 
----+-----------+---------+--------
  1 |         1 |       1 |      0
  2 |         1 |       2 |      1
  3 |         1 |       3 |      5
  4 |         2 |       1 |      1
  5 |         2 |       2 |      0
  6 |         2 |       3 |      0
  7 |         3 |       1 |      2
  8 |         3 |       2 |      3
  9 |         3 |       3 |      1
```

You can get the per-game rankings with this:

```
select game_id, player_id, points,
       rank() over (partition by game_id order by points desc)
from players
```

That will give you output like this:

```
 game_id | player_id | points | rank 
---------+-----------+--------+------
       1 |         3 |      2 |    1
       1 |         2 |      1 |    2
       1 |         1 |      0 |    3
       2 |         3 |      3 |    1
       2 |         1 |      1 |    2
       2 |         2 |      0 |    3
       3 |         1 |      5 |    1
       3 |         3 |      1 |    2
       3 |         2 |      0 |    3
```

Comment: @NikolayFominyh: Glad to help, I also have bears for neighbors and I have to defend my garbage from them :)

Answer (score 3):

This should do what you're searching for:

```
 SELECT game_id
 , row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY game_id ORDER BY points) AS num
 , array_agg(id) AS ids
 FROM players WHERE game_id = %s 
 GROUP BY game_id, points
 ORDER BY game_id, points
```