# Postgresql numbering groups of rows

Tags: postgresql, enumeration

I've next data table:

```
  id    date               another_info   
  1     2014-02-01         lala
  1     2014-03-11         ajskj
  1     2014-05-13         kgfd
  2     2014-02-01         SADA
  3     2014-02-01         sfdg
  3     2014-06-12         fdsA
  4     2015-01-03         lilo
  4     2015-01-07         kjlk
```

I want to attach column 'sequence_number':

```
  id    date           sequance_number    another_info
  1     2014-02-01          1              lala
  1     2014-03-11          2              ajskj
  1     2014-05-13          3              kgfd
  2     2014-02-01          1              SADA
  3     2014-02-01          1              sfdg
  3     2014-06-12          2              fdsA
  4     2015-01-03          1              lilo
  4     2015-01-07          2              kjlk
```

For each id, I numerate row. Table should be ordered by id, date

Comment: I recently find answer to my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9172621/enumerate-in-postgresql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [window function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-window.html).

```
select id,"date",another_info, row_number() OVER (ORDER BY id,"date") as sequence_number
from data_table
```

[EDIT] didn't realise you need to partition by id.

```
SELECT id,"date",another_info, 
row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY "date") as sequence_number
    FROM data_table
```